# Is it possible to write data from void_pointer to file in python ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, void-pointers, memory-address

I have a C-Program that acquires an image from my camera and writes the binary data to file.

I'm (thus far unsuccessfully) attempting to write a python script to mimic the C-code.

The Python ctypes example appears to execute without error UNTIL I try to write it to file.  In other words, in Python the `fwrite` is unable to write the data to file in this instance.  `fwrite` returns a value of `0`, indicating that `0` files were written.

**So, I am asking the following:** 
Since I have an external c-function that is reading out binary data, presumably to some buffer in memory, is it possible that the instance of Python ctypes simply does not have read access to this memory location?  And if that is the case, is it possible for python ctypes to *gain* the permission necessary to access the appropriate area in memory?

For reference, I have included a (working as expected) simplified C example followed by the Python ctypes example below, which opens and creates the appropriate file but does not write to it.

```
//Data Saving Sample
//The sample will open the first camera attached
//and acquire 3 frames.  The 3 frames will be saved
//in a raw format and can be opened with applications
//such as image-j

#define NUM_FRAMES  3
#define NO_TIMEOUT  -1

#include "stdio.h"
#include "picam.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // The following structure contains the image data
    AvailableData data;

    int readoutstride = 2097152;
    FILE *pFile;


    Acquire( NUM_FRAMES, NO_TIMEOUT, &data, &errors );

    pFile = fopen( "sampleX3.raw", "wb" );
    if( pFile )
    {
        fwrite( data.initial_readout, 1, (NUM_FRAMES*readoutstride), pFile );
        fclose( pFile );
    }

}
```

And here is my Python version:

```
""" Load the picam.dll """
picamDll = 'DLLs/Picam.dll'
picam = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(picamDll)

libc = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt
fopen = libc.fopen

data = AvailableData()
readoutstride = ctypes.c_int(2097152)

"""
This is the C-structure form from the provided header file, followed by the Python syntax for creating the same structure type
typedef struct AvailableData
{
    void* initial_readout;
    int64 readout_count;
} AvailableData;

class AvailableData(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("initial_readout", ctypes.c_void_p), ("readout_count",ctypes.c_int64)]
"""

"""
Simplified C-Prototype for Acquire

Acquire(
int64                       readout_count,
int                       readout_time_out,
AvailableData*         available);
"""
picam.Acquire.argtypes = int64, int, ctypes.POINTER(AvailableData)

picam.Acquire.restype = int

print picam.Acquire( 3, -1, ctypes.byref(data), ctypes.byref(errors))

""" Write contents of Data to binary file """
fopen.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p
fopen.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

fwrite = libc.fwrite
fwrite.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_void_p
fwrite.restype = ctypes.c_int

fclose = libc.fclose
fclose.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p,
fclose.restype = ctypes.c_int

fp = fopen('PythonBinOutput.raw', 'wb')
print 'fwrite returns: ',fwrite(data.initial_readout, 3*readoutstride.value, 1, fp)
fclose(fp)
```

Comment: It would be much better if you stripped out all the unrelated Picam stuff, which makes it hard for people to test and debug your code. See http://sscce.org for some ideas on what makes good example code for a question.

Comment: @abarnert agreed -- just did some cleanup thanks

Comment: Meanwhile, what exactly is in readoutstride.value? Are you sure it's not 0?

Comment: @abarnert yes, I can call a function that returns what value it should be, which is `2097152`.  I left out that part of the code for simplification.  Incidentally this corresponds to a 1024x1024x2 bytes.  The camera is 16 bit and is 1024x1024.

Comment: The edited version still isn't runnable without Picam. You should be able to repro the problem without using it at all. For example, just use Python to create a `c_char_p` with 3*2097152 bytes of data, then `cast`it to `c_void_p`. Or, alternatively, call a standard C function that gives you a `c_void_p` with the data in it. If you _can't_ repro the problem that way, whatever's going wrong must be in the Picam code. If you _can_, other people can debug the problem for you.

Comment: Also, have you tried checking `errno` and/or calling `ferror` if it returns 0? Knowing what the error is would make life a lot easier… Meanwhile, for this part: "is it possible that the instance of Python ctypes simply does not have read access to this memory location?" No, it isn't. Memory access is process-wide; you can't have memory that's readable by one module (msvcrt) and not by another (python) in the same process.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for these ideas.  I will try what you suggested (create a c_char_p with 3*2097152 bytes of data, then cast it to c_void_p).  I will also look into ferror -- I'm not familiar with this otherwise I would've checked into it earlier.  I will post updates when I do those two things, thanks!

Comment: Do you know where to find the docs for these functions? Assuming you don't want to run Visual Studio, you can usually just search `msdn fwrite`, and get a link to [the MSDN docs for `fwrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9t88zwz(v=vs.71).aspx). Also, when you're dealing with any C-standard function, and with many POSIX functions that MSVCRT has (either with or without the preceding underscore), you may want to look at [a Unix man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite) by searching `man fwrite`, because they sometimes have better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to use with a regular Python file. For example:

Get a void pointer:

```
class AvailableData(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("initial_readout", c_void_p), 
    ]

cglobals = CDLL(None) # POSIX dlopen
cglobals.malloc.restype = c_void_p

size = 100  # 3 * readoutstride.value
data = AvailableData(cglobals.malloc(size))
```

Now use it as an array:

```
buf = (c_char * size).from_address(data.initial_readout)
with open('PythonBinOutput.raw', 'wb') as f: 
    f.write(buf)
```